# Routed IPv6 range and WAN IPv6 range in different subnets

Tags: networking, ipv6, wide-area-network

I have a datasheet from my ISP stating a "WAN IPv6 Range" and a "Routed IPv6 Range". When I configure my IPv6 on my router I use a static IPv6 configuration with my WAN range and get a successful connection and it works. I also enter the routed range in the configuration, but it does not show up in neither my local LAN nor as a WAN IP address.

The WAN IPv6 Range is a /64 and the Routed is a /48, but they are not in the same subnet and the routed range is bigger. From everything I could research myself I cannot make sense of this. What is the difference between these two ranges and how do I use them correctly? And where should the WAN IP range appear and where the Routed IP range and how do I check that?

Any pointer in the correct direction is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You divide the `/48` range into standard `/64` networks for use on your LAN networks (you have 65,536 `/64` networks you can derive from the `/48` network). The WAN `/64` network should be used on your router WAN interface, and the `/64` networks derived from your `/48` LAN block should be assigned to your router LAN interfaces and any other networks you use in your LAN.

If your router supports IPv6 Prefix Delegation, you can use that to assign the `/64` networks in your LAN, otherwise you need to do it manually.

Comment: Why is the WAN adress different though? Where does the WAN /64 go if I already know that my real network should be in the /48 range? Also why is my actual public facing in the /64 range and not in the actual /48 range? I just don't get what belongs to what and why :/ Why do I not only have the /48 if that is my actual address in the network?

Comment: Routers route packets _between_ networks. Your ISP has given you a transit link network and a prefix that can be divided into standard-sized networks. This is a typical way to do things. The ISP controls the smaller prefix of the transit link (probably dividing a`/48` or smaller prefix into `/64` transit links for different customers), and it gives you complete control over the prefix you use for networks in your LAN, letting you divide the `/48` prefix into longer prefixes for your own use. The ISP only need to know to route traffic destined for the `/48` to you for your internal routing.

Comment: I tried a bit more with the additional information. So you are saying that the /64 prefix is only a transit network that should not be used by anything other than the router? So my actual public facing IP address should be in the /48 network? Because now I reconfigured my router to use DHCPv6 with PD to do the IPv6 configuration and now my IP addresses are not in the /64 range anymore, but actually in the /48 range (the /64 is not part of the /48). So this is how it was meant all along? But how was I even allowed to get addresses in the /64 range before :/

Comment: Yes, the /48 is for your use, and contains 64 thousand /64s.  Consider the WAN /64 exclusively for the WAN link, following the /64 for every net principle.  Even if the /64 is otherwise unused and routed to you, don't worry about it.

Comment: @SkryptX "_So my actual public facing IP address should be in the /48 network?_" You need to let go of the IPv4 thinking. All the IPv6 addressing you have is public addressing; you do not worry about public/private addressing with IPv6 like you do with IPv4. The WAN link uses the transit `/64` network (a public network), and your internal networks use `/64` network addressing derived from the `/48` prefix (all that is also public addressing). IPv6 restores the IP end-to-end paradigm where _every_ host gets a unique _public_ IP address, and you avoid all the problems inherent in NAT/NAPT.

Comment: @SkryptX You may be interested in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53937/8499) that explains the limitations of and mitigations for IPv4 (you need to forget about those with IPv6), and it also explains how IPv6 is the long-term solution for the IPv4 address shortage, but also how the IETF took lessons learned from IPv4 to better IP in IPv6.

Comment: "Public facing IP address" in this context I mean the IP address which others see when I visit their sites and so on. That's what I meant by that and since the configuration was wrong before I had multiple different IPv6 addresses on my computer and this lead to a lot of confusion how this all works since it was all over the place. I think I understand now how it works and what I have to look for. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SkryptX "_I mean the IP address which others see_" Yes, that is exactly what I mean. The other sites you visit will see that IP address of the host from which you are connecting. It is your old IPv4/NAT/NAPT thinking that the sites will only see one address (the router WAN address) from all the hosts in your network. _Every_ one of your hosts will connect from its own unique public address, and each of those addresses are the addresses that the sites to which you connect will see. In fact, the sites will never see your router WAN address unless you connect from the router itself.

Comment: It's ok, I got that :) I can verify myself now that my PC and my smartphone have different IPv6 addresses even though they have the same IPv4 address, because my router NATs them. Both devices are now in the <routed prefix>:0::  /64 range of my /48 address space, while my router connects itself with the transit network. Everything fits now as it should :D